# Dropdown Not having list tag or select tag only input tag and tag is dynamically changing after dropdown appears then how to select dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="returnReason" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-b52kj1" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" value="">
```

This is my webelement for a dropdown but only this tag element changes when we select the dropdown element no any new tag or anything generates then how we can select a first element of a dropdown.
aria controls are changing only like "aria-activedescendentoption-1".
please help me with this.

i tried a ui li list but it does not have ui li tag.